# Virtual Machine 'XY' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running, however it's running and started correctly on Windows 2022

Tags: windows, vmware, hyper-v

I have tried to configure an RDS Hyper-V environment for VDI on an up-to-date Windows 2022 Server, running on a VMWare ESXi v5.5 host. Everything seems to be set, up, and running, although when I try to run the VM inside Hyper-V Manager, I get "Virtual Machine 'XY' could not be started because the hypervisor is not running" error message.

I have found a bunch of solutions, unfortunately non of them worked so far.

What I have tried so far:

1. Uninstall/Install the entire RDS Virtualization Host Role
2. Uninstall/Install Hyper-V Features
3. **vmcompute** and **vmms** services are running, but i have tried restarting vmcompute,vmms services manually too
4. bcdedit /set HypervisorLaunchType Auto

   Checking it with bcdedit /enum {current} shows that it's Auto
5. Remove Problematic Updates (non of them were present)

> Run "wusa /uninstall /kb:5009624"

> Run "wusa /uninstall /kb:5009595"

> Run "wusa /uninstall /kb:5009555"

6. Enabled CPU Virtualization in VMWare (Use Intel VT-x/AMD-V)
7. Also Changed VMX file of the VM

> vhv.enable = "TRUE"

> hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"

8. DEEP Enable - Win + Pause > Advanced System Settings > Performance > Settings > Data Execution Prevention > "Turn on DEP for essential Windows programs and services only"
9. dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All

Nothing seems to work, and I ran out of ideas. Based on diagnostics, everything ok, but the VMs still doesn't start.

Some diagnostics that I ran:

> cmd.exe systeminfo|find "Second Level"

```
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
```

> cmd.exe systeminfo

```
VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

> coreinfo64.exe -v

URL: (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722)

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 00000036
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
URG             *       Supports Intel unrestricted guest
```

13. gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security, and set to Disabled. Reboot.

Is there anything else that I could try? Based on my internet research, it should work, but maybe I am missing something obvious here. I would appreciate any help, further idea or recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after trying out all the solutions that are suggested on the web, I still got the same error message as you. What I did in the end was enter the command `sfc /scannow` in the PowerShell (did it in admin mode, not sure if it is necessary though). SFC scans your Windows for corrupted files and fixes them as best as it can. After that, both my Linux and Windows 10 VMs worked perfectly well.